# Spreadsheet Not Rendering Data

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I am using kendo-ui's spreadsheet widget in an attempt to load read-only data on the fly. Since, so far as I am aware, there is no way to import a CSV literal, I am converting my CSV data to the appropriate format by using the jquery-csv library along with the $.map function.

This is what I am doing:

```
var rows = $.csv.toArrays(viewModel.Csv);

$("#spreadsheet-preview").data("kendoSpreadsheet").activeSheet().rows = $.map(rows, function(row) {
    return {
        "cells": $.map(row, function(cell) {
            return {
                "background": "#ffffff",
                "color": "#343a40",
                "enable": false,
                "value": cell
            }
        })
    };
});
$("#spreadsheet-preview").data("kendoSpreadsheet").refresh();
```

Whenever I inspect the result of `$("#spreadsheet-preview").data("kendoSpreadsheet").activeSheet().rows` in my browser's console afterwards, the returned value is:

```
[
  {
    "cells": [
      {
        "background": "#ffffff",
        "color": "#343a40",
        "enable": false,
        "value": "John"
      },
      {
        "background": "#ffffff",
        "color": "#343a40",
        "enable": false,
        "value": "Smith"
      },
      {
        "background": "#ffffff",
        "color": "#343a40",
        "enable": false,
        "value": "5555551234"
      },
      {
        "background": "#ffffff",
        "color": "#343a40",
        "enable": false,
        "value": "user@email.com"
      },
      {
        "background": "#ffffff",
        "color": "#343a40",
        "enable": false,
        "value": "123 Main St"
      },
      {
        "background": "#ffffff",
        "color": "#343a40",
        "enable": false,
        "value": "Anytown"
      },
      {
        "background": "#ffffff",
        "color": "#343a40",
        "enable": false,
        "value": "LA"
      },
      {
        "background": "#ffffff",
        "color": "#343a40",
        "enable": false,
        "value": "12345"
      },
      {
        "background": "#ffffff",
        "color": "#343a40",
        "enable": false,
        "value": "4/19/2020"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Which is what I would expect it to be, however the widget never updates to reflect the new data, regardless of the `refresh()` called after I set the rows property.

Is this a bug or am I just missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I know that I asked this question 15 minutes ago, but I was able to resolve the issue.

By setting `rows` on the `activeSheet`, I was creating a previously undefined property of the returned object. Instead, I had to call the [fromJSON method](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/spreadsheet/sheet/methods/fromjson) and pass the method an object with a `rows` property with my mapping.

Here was the solution:

```
$("#spreadsheet-preview").data("kendoSpreadsheet").activeSheet().fromJSON({
    "rows": $.map(rows, function(row) {
        return {
            "cells": $.map(row, function(cell) {
                return {
                    "background": "#ffffff",
                    "color": "#343a40",
                    "enable": false,
                    "value": cell
                }
            })
        };
    })
});
```